# Regarding grouping in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, melt

I have this data frame and I want to group expected column with different individual patient data. I wrote the code but it works for 1 patient only. I wanted to do this for 14 patients. As shown in figure this graph is for 1 patient and I have to display similar group for all the patients.  Currently I have the data for 2 patients. So I have to  label the x axis for 14 patients but leave the plot as empty

[image: hand drawn].

[image]

```
c<- data.frame(Var=character(), 
               Expected=double(),
                         Pat_1=double(),
                         Pat_2=double(),
                         stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
x<-data.frame("IT-6",2,4,3)
names(x)<-c('Var','Expected','Pat_1','Pat_2')
c<-rbind(c,x)

x<-data.frame("IT-7",3,2,8)
names(x)<-c('Var','Expected','Pat_1','Pat_2')
c<-rbind(c,x)

x<-data.frame("IT-8",4,2,7)
names(x)<-c('Var','Expected','Pat_1','Pat_2')
c<-rbind(c,x)

c_melt<-melt(c, id = c("Var"))
c_melt<-dplyr::rename(c_melt,"Patient"="variable")
c_melt$col<-ifelse(grepl("Expected", c_melt$Patient),"gray88","grey60")

> c_melt
   Var  Patient value    col
1 IT-6 Expected     2 gray88
2 IT-7 Expected     3 gray88
3 IT-8 Expected     4 gray88
4 IT-6    Pat_1     4 grey60
5 IT-7    Pat_1     2 grey60
6 IT-8    Pat_1     2 grey60
7 IT-6    Pat_2     3 grey60
8 IT-7    Pat_2     8 grey60
9 IT-8    Pat_2     7 grey60


ggplot(data=c_melt,aes(x=Var,y=value,fill=col))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", na.rm = T,position="dodge")+
  labs(y="Display(%)",x="")+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=12,angle=0,vjust = 0.5,face = c( 'bold')),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.ticks=element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.border =  element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=0.5),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y  = element_text(size=15,angle=0,vjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=12,angle=0,vjust = 0.5))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+ 
scale_fill_identity()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try facet_wrap

```
ggplot(data=c_melt,aes(x=Var,y=value,fill=col))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", na.rm = T,position="dodge")+
  facet_wrap(~Patient) +
```

Comment: no the expected has to be grouped with pat_1 and Pat_2 ,as I showed in plot, and not as separate.

Comment: Try fill=Patient, not fil=col  That col variable looks weird to me because there are two levels instead of three   just a thought

Comment: @joseph fill=col is for differentiating based on color.Also fill=Patient will group based on var but I want it to be grouped like Pat_1+Expected and Pat_2+Expected

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a better example to show what you're after.

Here are a couple of ideas that either fills on Patient, or groups on Patient while filling on col. How do they compare?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tibble)

c_melt <- tibble( Var = c("IT-6","IT-7","IT-8","IT-6","IT-7","IT-8","IT-6","IT-7","IT-8"),
                  Patient = c("Expected","Expected","Expected","Pat_1","Pat_1","Pat_1","Pat_2","Pat_2","Pat_2"),
                  value = c(2,3,4,4,2,2,3,8,7),
                  col = c("gray88","gray88","gray88","gray60","gray60","gray60","gray60","gray60","gray60")
                )

#Example 1
c_melt %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=Var,y=value,fill=Patient))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", na.rm = T,position="dodge")
```

[image]

```r
#Example 2
c_melt %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=Var,y=value,fill=col, group=Patient))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", na.rm = T,position="dodge") +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: the above graph(on the top) is for patient 1 .light grey is for expected and dark grey is for Pat_1.Now I want to repeat this graph for Pat_2 also. For Pat_2 also light grey will be expected and dark grey would be Pat_2 and it would go on for Pat_3.  If you see c variable it contains 4 columns var,Expected,Pat_1,Pat_2....I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: @Micky can you draw a mockup of what you want the plot to look like? I can't see it from your description.

Comment: I have edited the post. You can see the hand drawn image above.

Comment: I got the answer as a follow of another post.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64603025/regarding-factoring-in-r)

Thanks for the help.